# allow digits only for inputs

Tags: javascript, parsing

I;m trying yo implement a javacript function which will not allow to the user to input anything else than float numbers (digits)

This is my approach but I don't know how to improve it in order to allow submition of negatives numbers also (allow '-' key) and work on IE also.

```
function digits_only(evt, form) {
    var evt = evt || window.event,
        targ = evt.target || evt.srcElement,
        charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode,
        keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode),
        isValid = true;
    if (charCode > 13) {
        isValid = /[0-9.]/.test(keyChar);
        //if a dolt is already in input
        if (keyChar === '.' && /\./.test(targ.value)) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: HI,
Is this a good approach? What happens if the user copies or drags some text into the input box. I think you should better do validation on submit event.

Comment: yes, validation should be added too, but what he ask for now was restricting input

Comment: But you cannot be sure by which way the user enters input. He can type, paste or even drag some text.

Comment: +1. Don't interfere with the user's typing, it's just annoying and doesn't cover all possible ways to altering the field.

Comment: client side is more cheaper...I'll do the validation on submit too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for so called "input masks". They are a lot more powerful then just allowing numbers. But you can surly use them for that. Google "javascript input mask" or check out [this jQuery Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

EDIT:
Seems like the linked plugin only supports fixed length masks, but the term may be a good starting point...

Answer (score 1):

Is this on an ASP.NET web application? You could use the AjaxControlToolkits MaskEditExtender.

Answer (score 0):

I have asking similar question here:
[restrict user input using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657492/restrict-user-input-using-javascript)

but no one give the exact answer for the problem, so let's wait until WebForms 2.0 released

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to "InputEvent" and then get "data" prop. For example

```
input.addEventListener('beforeinput', (event) => {
    const data = event.data;

    // if "data" is present - user enter some character
    // if "data" is NOT present - user tap non character key (e.g. delete, shift and other)
    if(data) {
        // check if data is number or "."
        const isAllow = /\d|\./.test(data);

        if(!isAllow) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
})
```

More info

1. event.data - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data
2. beforeinput event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event