# How do I check if the key pressed on a form field is a digit (0 - 9)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using the `onkeyup` event on a form field in JavaScript, and I'm wanting to check if the key the key pressed is a numeric digit - i.e. 0 - 9, so I can then do something with the input.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="" />
```

Would I need to use Regex for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See these:

- [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)
- [allow digits only for inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724217/allow-digits-only-for-inputs)

Comment: +1 for redirecting the user to earlier stackoverflow entries.

Comment: Those depend on jQuery. Probably should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 23):

Use `event.key` to get the actual value. To check if integer, just use `isFinite`

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    const isNumber = isFinite(event.key);
});
```

Other option:

```
const isNumber = /^[0-9]$/i.test(event.key)
```

An easier HTML solution would be to use the `number` type input. It restricts to only numbers (kind of).

```
<input type="number">
```

Either way, you should clean all user input with:

```
string.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

Comment: Interesting.. I've seen references to `e.which`, `e.keyCode`, etc... but this is the first time I've seen someone say `e.key`, which seems like the best answer to me... Is there any downside to using it?

Comment: Remember that, isFinite is ES6 feature and KeyboardEvent.key is not fully supported yet.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `isFinite` will be `true` for values like '4.6' and `null`. That isn't really an issue during a keypress event (where you can assess a single character at a time), but it's sometimes dangerous to use functions depending on implementation rather than on their purpose.

Comment: Just noticed that `isFinite` returns true for spacebar key press. The solution was `if (!isFinite(e.key) || e.key === ' ') e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: isFinite(event.key); returns true for also space, beware

Answer (score 2):

I used the following function to check if a given string is number or not

```
// Validate Numeric inputs
function isNumber(o) {
    return o == '' || !isNaN(o - 0);
}
```

Assuming that your key code on the keyup or keydown event is in keyCode variable:

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) {
        // Numpad keys
        keyCode -= 48;
}
console.log(isNumber(String.fromCharCode(keyCode)));
```

Answer (score 2):

allow only 0-9, other letters will be swallowed.

```
$('#id').keypress(function (e) {
            var validkeys = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
            if (validkeys.indexOf(e.key) < 0)
                return false;
        });
```

Comment: Not usable solution because you cant move in input using arrow, or delete to edit input.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to "InputEvent" and then get "data" prop. For example

```
input.addEventListener('beforeinput', (event) => {
    const data = event.data;

    // if "data" is present - user enter some character
    // if "data" is NOT present - user tap non character key (e.g. delete, shift and other)
    if(data) {
        const isAllow = /\d/.test(data);

        if(!isAllow) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
})
```

More info

1. event.data - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data
2. beforeinput event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event

Answer (score 0):

```js
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if (isNaN(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note that the question is 'Would I need to use Regex for this?'. A code fragment maybe a too  brief answer. Can you improve your answer?

Answer (score -1):

See this:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayunicode(e){
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
if unicode >= 48 && unicode <= 57 {
    alert('number')
}
else{
}
    alert('nonnumber')
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="displayunicode(event); this.select()" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is not exact, you have to insert also they numpad numbers. http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-key-codes